# Uploading and Downloading file by using Salesforce1

Tags: force.com, mobile, salesforce1-app

I am trying to upload a  .csv format file into salesforce.The upload is working fine on browser. using myinstance/one/one.app
And  I am also trying to download a file in specific format file for example

```
 <apex:page title="contact.vcf" cache="True" contentType="text/x-vcard#{!Contact.id}.vcf" standardcontroller="Contact">
```

This is also working fine on desktop browser.

However when i log on to the Mobile Salesforce1 app nothing happens in both of the cases.
The browse button doesn't works in upload case and in download nothing gets downloaded.

Both pages are marked to be used on mobile.

Comment: can you add your code ?Are you using custom vf or standard button?

Comment: This is a custom visualforce page. That is binded with a Publisher action.Things are working fine when emulation done on google chrome using myinstance/one/one.app. Code is very simple i am only showing fields using standard controller on page.    <apex:page title="contact.vcf" cache="True" contentType="text/x-vcard#{!Contact.id}.vcf" standardcontroller="Contact"> This must download the file in vcf format, but this doesn't works.

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce1 app has restriction for download and upload using its application. They have disabled that feature in their app for Android version. "choose file" won't work.

Salesforce1 app has major dependency on `WebView` on Android/iOS platform. It may cause security risk to application to allow access to external files freely. This will cause unexpected behaviour of application and `WebView` may start working out of the context of Salesforce. So it is better to disable it temporarily. 
However iOS support upload file functionality from Salesforce1 app. Not sure about downloading.